# Regular expression for span tag

Tags: php, regex

How to regex span tag exp.

```
<span id="n1">value here</span>
```

I need to get span id and "value here"?

Comment: You shouldn't use regex to parse HTML. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use regex to parse HTML.  However, if you must, this should do it.

```
$regex = '#<span id="(.+?)">(.+?)</span>#';
preg_match($regex, $input, $groups);

$id = $groups[1];
$value = $groups[2];
```

This is in no ways absolutely bulletproof.  Not by a long shot.

You should really take a look at something like [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/domdocument)

Comment: Nilpo have error: Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '('...